# DST change handling in a daemon process (*NIX)

Tags: c++, linux, dst, timezone

In a *NIX environment, if I have a 24x7 running application, how do I handle DST changes?
I am looking for a solution for my app written in C/C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would a deamon use anything else that UTC time?

Comment: I guess i didnt have the right mind set!

The reason why I asked was, some of the third party library (not OSS) I have been using is having strange behaviour when the DST changes! So I was messing around to see if I can do anything about it.

Comment: Try so set things up so that it uses the "C" locale (environment variable LC_ALL set to C)